# How to login moodle with requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, moodle

I am trying to make login moodle with python script but there is "session expired" error. Here is code:

```
 import requests
 import re

 login = 12345678
 passwd = 'password'

 r = requests.get("https://moodle.site.com/login/index.php")
 cookie = r.cookies.get_dict()
 pattern = '<input type="hidden" name="logintoken" value="\w{32}">'
 token = re.findall(pattern, r.text)
 token = re.findall("\w{32}", token[0])
 payload = {'username': login, 'password': pass, 'anchor': '', 'logintoken': token[0]}
 r = requests.post("https://moodle.site.com/login/index.php", cookies=cookie, data=payload)
 print(r)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `pass` as an variable.Rename it to `password` is okay.

Comment: thanks, but what about problem?

Comment: I couldn't open the page.

Comment: because that's a fake page, choose another real website

Answer (score 2):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass-stmt) is a null operation in python.You shouldn't use it as the name of the variable.That's why it will raise Exception.

You could use the code below:

```
import requests
import re

login = 12345678
passwd = 'password'

r = requests.get("https://moodle.site.com/login/index.php")
cookie = r.cookies.get_dict()
pattern = '<input type="hidden" name="logintoken" value="\w{32}">'
token = re.findall(pattern, r.text)
token = re.findall("\w{32}", token[0])
payload = {'username': login, 'password': passwd, 'anchor': '', 'logintoken': token[0]}
r = requests.post("https://moodle.site.com/login/index.php", cookies=cookie, data=payload)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
import requests
import re

app_data = {
    "login": "LOG",
    "password": "PASS",
    "url": "https://UR_DOMAIN/login/index.php"
}


def auth_moodle(data: dict) -> requests.Session():
    login, password, url_domain = data.values()
    s = requests.Session()
    r_1 = s.get(url=url_domain + "/login/index.php")
    pattern_auth = '<input type="hidden" name="logintoken" value="\w{32}">'
    token = re.findall(pattern_auth, r_1.text)
    token = re.findall("\w{32}", token[0])[0]
    payload = {'anchor': '', 'logintoken': token, 'username': login, 'password': password, 'rememberusername': 1}
    r_2 = s.post(url=url_domain + "/login/index.php", data=payload)
    for i in r_2.text.splitlines():
        if "<title>" in i:
            print(i[15:-8:])
            break
    counter = 0
    for i in r_2.text.splitlines():
        if "loginerrors" in i or (0 < counter <= 3):
            counter += 1
            print(i)
    return s


print(auth_moodle(data=app_data))
```

Comment: Hope i helped you