# Why do I have to save both a png and txt file when downloading an image in python?

Tags: python, php, authentication, session, request

What im trying to do is download an image from a link using requests, the only issue is I need to log in to do this, so this is why I have the make_session function, its purpose is to log in. I should also say my code works, but I don't know why it works, the way I got it working makes no sense to me, so first ill explain how I got there.

at first my code only saved one file, either a .txt or .png depending on when I ran it (The txt was useful for seeing if it was logged in), the code would log in when I only saved a .txt but not when I only saved a .png, the only thing I was changing in between runs was the variable filename. It is very easy when you actually run the code to see if it worked as the filesize when it failed to log in was 32kb for both the txt and the png, however the png did not open (obviously). This was already baffling me as the extension of the file saved shouldn't be the sole factor in determining if it works.

Eventually I tried saving a png and txt and it works, the png displays properly and is the same size as the txt file, the order there saved in also doesn't matter as both orders work. So my main question is why? Right now I just save an extra txt file and its not a big deal but I'm absolutely baffled as to why this is needed, I should also say I have tested this thoroughly enough to where I'm 100% confident this is the only change made between when it works and does not.

This is also part of a larger code but no where else in the code is the session used or any of the variables in either function is used (this is the only part that can possibly affect it.)

```
def make_session():
    s = requests.Session()
    user, password = '****', '****'

    r = s.get("https://moodle-ts.adlc.ca/login/index.php")
    cookie = r.cookies.get_dict()
    pattern = '<input type="hidden" name="logintoken" value="\w{32}">'
    token = re.findall(pattern, r.text)
    token = re.findall("\w{32}", token[0])
    payload = {'username': user, 'password': password, 'anchor': '', 'logintoken': token[0], 'rememberusername': 1}
    r = s.post("https://moodle-ts.adlc.ca/login/index.php", cookies=cookie, data=payload)   
    return(s)


def download_image(page_content, driver, s):
    images = page_content.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")      
    for img in images:
        src = img.get_attribute('src')
        ext = src[-3:]
        file_name = "image." + "png"    
        img_info = s.get(src)
    
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img_info.content)
            f.close()
        with open("image.txt", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img_info.content)
            f.close()
```

I got much of the make_session function from [How to login moodle with requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228782/how-to-login-moodle-with-requests)

Any insight as to why this is happening would be much appreciated as I would love to understand this better!

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is that the server blocks too many requests in a short time period and the additional file writing slows it down appropriately. That writing only a txt file worked but only a png didn't is probably coincidence.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tryed sleeping between requests and that did not fix it and the png not working was extensively tested (10+ times), I will add that it did work with just png at one point, when make_session did not exist and that code was inside (also tried before) the loop, the issue was it only worked for the first link passed in then would "logout" after.

Comment: @python_user Its possible, they do show up as 2 separate files in the folder and deleting one doesn't affect the other

Comment: @python_user Exactly, I have no idea why the extension of the file is what makes it work or not.